# How to get current logged in username in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created one intranet application in ASP.NET MVC 4.
I have added login module with Windows Login. So That User can login in application with different windows logins.
Currently now I get the current login user details with

```
    string currentuser = User.Identity.Name;
```

It displays the current windows login username.
But in my application, user can logout and login with different windows login username, then still that variable gives the windows login username instead of application login username.

Give me the right code to fetch the current application logged on username instead of windows logged in username. Help

Comment: When the user logs out, are you calling WebSecurity.Logout() ? it sounds like the session isn't being cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

you can get like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;



string username = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
```

or try with this:

```
stirng user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: i am currently using mvc4 and your given suggestion use in mvc5.

Comment: you can try this as well: HttpContext.Current.User;